# Change Axis Order when transferring data from WFS to PostGIS DB

Tags: coordinate-system, well-known-text, epsg, geokettle

I am using GeoKettle to transfer data from a WFS service to a PostGIS database.

The projection of the geometries is EPSG:4326 :

```
GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
    SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
  PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
  UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
  AXIS["Longitude", EAST], 
  AXIS["Latitude", NORTH], 
  AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
```

In the data I have latitude/longitude tuples. When it's imported into PostGIS, it appears as longitude/latitude.

I want to specify a CRS WKT parameter so that when data is imported into PostGIS, the geometries will appear where they should.

Is this even possible with an CRS conversion?

Comment: Odd WKT for the projection. It claims that it is EPSG:4326 but still that axis order is Longitude-Latitude. And you say that data use latitude-longitude. Something does not match.

Comment: I know, I'm very confused. I managed to operate directly on the Database to change the axis order. There is a ST_FlipCoordinates procedure in Postgis that does the trick, even though it involves some work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your WKT doesn't define any axis order, just lists them.

You could try with WKT 2 that defines axes order like:

```
GEODCRS["WGS 84",
  DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
    ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,LENGTHUNIT["metre",1.0]]],
  CS[ellipsoidal,2],
    AXIS["latitude",north,ORDER[1]],
    AXIS["longitude",east,ORDER[2]],
    ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.01745329252],
  ID["EPSG",4326]]
```

This is the official WKT definition from the EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset (www.epsg-registry.org)